# Hold down right mouse click with Pyautogui

Tags: python

I need to hold down the right mouse button for a script I'm working on. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do
`pyautogui.mouseDown(button="right");`
More parameters and documentation can be found [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#the-mousedown-and-mouseup-functions)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
pyautogui.drag(10, 0, 0, button='right')
I am on mobile and i cant convert it to code sorry.